# Assigning element of list of lists by index sets all first elements of the lists

Tags: python, list, indexing, sublist

I have a list of 3 values per month that a initialized like this:

```
v=[[0.0,0.0,0.0]]*12
```

In 2 nested loops I want to add a value to an element:

```
v[month-1][pos] += row[0]
```

At one point in the execution of the code `month-1 = 8` and `pos = 0`. `row[0]` which I get from a query to a database is `1.0`.

Strangely as result I get 
`[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0,....` 
So the first element of every sub-list is set to `1.0`. How can this happen? Even more strange is if I debug the code and manually set the value `v[8][0]=9` or so it works as intended.

Comment: You're initializing your v list to contain 12 instances of the same list (`v[0] is v[1]` etc.). You need to initialize these instances to a new list each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this `v=[[0.0,0.0,0.0]]*12` you are getting a list with 12 references to the same list, to fix that use a comprehension instead:

```
v = [[0.0,0.0,0.0] for _ in range(12)]
```

Usually the `*` used like this should not be wanted to use over mutable elements.